# Debug cordova ionic in Browser (deviceready, fileapi)

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

**1. I want debug cordova project in Chrome**

Have typical angular .run

```js
.run(function ($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $ionicConfig, $timeout, $state) {
    console.log('run');
    $ionicPlatform.on('deviceready', function () {
        console.log('deviceready');
    });
```

But *console.log('deviceready')* not run

**Why deviceready not fired?**

**2. Storage for Android/iOS/WP/Browser**

For caching data (up to 100MB) I need identical storage  for all plafroms. I found it`s
*https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file*

It`s best plugin for **one code for all platforms**?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
ionic.Platform.ready(function(){

    //your code 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ionic supports "browser" platform, which is great for debugging, you can add this platform and use it as a debug intermediate